# How to add controller parameter when calling refresh for Kendo Grid from Javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

Here is the section of the kendo grid within razor that handles the read sync.

```
.Read(read => read.Action("GetRecords", "SoftwareSecurity", new { showAll = false }))
```

The reason i have it set in here to false is that we do not want to display all values on initial load.

This is the controller method called in the read function of the kendo grid built within a Razor syntax:

```
public ActionResult GetRecords([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, bool showAll = false)
    {
        int total = 0;
        string filter = Request.Form["filter"];
        string sort = Request.Form["sort"];
        int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["pageSize"]);
        int pageNum = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["page"]);

        [rest of code not needed for here.....] (returns json)

}
```

Now, I have a show all button that i bind to a front end javascript function. When using this, i am wondering how to also pass the "Show All" parameter to the controller call. This calls the exact same controller.

```
function showAll() {
    var grid = $("#userAccessGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    $filter = new Array();
    $filter.push({ field: "CustID", operator: "gt", value: "0" });
    grid.dataSource.filter($filter);
}
```

So once again, how can i also override the extra controller parameter when calling the javascript function "Show All"?

Comment: I was hoping they let you populate extra params in the post, but doesn't work. $filter.push({ field: "CustID", operator: "gt", value: "0", showAll: false }); It allows me to post to controller, but does not map the new custom attribute.

Comment: I want to add other params beyond show all as i can edit the filter string. I guess i can make custom filters and pull values from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by adding the `Data` Property at the end of the call.

```
.Read(read => read.Action("GetRecords", "SoftwareSecurity").Data("someJavacriptFunctionHere"))
```

then all you need to do is call the function with whatever logic you need to go into it so you can pass that data back. like:

```
function someJavacriptFunctionHere(){

return {showAll: true, someOtherOptionHere: true}; 
}
```

As long as you either have them mapped as individual properties on your controller or as and class they should be fired back to the controller. I use this method a lot for when I am doing more `complex` requirements that take form data from other areas of the page or from custom buttons I use.